# Bootstarp 4 - grid system- fixed items in flex-box

Tags: bootstrap-4, flexbox, row, css-grid, grid-system

in medium size and upward until large screen the second image height not equal with others images
[enter image description here][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qcytg.png

```
<div class="container">
          <div class="row "> 
            <% campgrounds.forEach(function(campground){ %>
              <div class="col-sm text-center d-flex align-items-strech">
                      <div class="card">
                      <img class="card-img-top" src="<%=campground.image%>" alt="Card image cap">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h3 class="card-title"><%=campground.name%></h3>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p> 
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              <% }); %>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you please post all of the relevant HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You can add align-self-end class to that button to align it at the bottom.